# Vyper gas uint64 overflow error

Tags: web3.py, evm, python, vyper

im trying to deploy a Vyper contract, it compiles, but then, when im deploying it, raise the exception {'code': -32000, 'message': 'gas uint64 overflow'}.

Only when I add a value to the HashMap, it works, but the compiler raise another error instead. Specifically, i add self.token_list[EMPTY_BYTES32] = empty(uint256).

[There is the contract code](https://github.com/jossemii/VyperGasDeposit/blob/b78bdbce93b4f2df08b7008b6f89a011a6391cb9/contracts/contract.vy)

Comment: How are you deploying the contract?